# Angular 6, access component variable inside ngFor scope

Tags: angular, ngfor, angular-components

How can I access a components global variable inside a ngFor loop scope (which is in the html template of the component).

Please don't tell me this isn't possible, I'm disappointed enough with Angular already.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let option of options">
   <label class="{{globalVariable}}">{{option}}</label>
</ng-container>
```

This doesn't work. How can I use 'globalVariable' inside the ngFor scope?

The 'globalVariable' is define in the component like so:

```
@Input() globalVariable: 'someClass';
```

Comment: Is `globalVariable` a class?

Comment: Can you please provide your component code where you have your global variable.

Comment: Where you have defined globalVariable ? `class="{{globalVariable}}"` or `[ngclass]="globalVariable"` both are equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

Use ngClass directive.

```
<p [ngClass]="red">
  Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kiz9y4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

Pass the parameter `globalVariable` as like (Note the single quote):

```
<app-temp [globalVariable]="'globalVariable'"></app-temp>
```

Then it will work as you are expecting:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let option of options">
   <div class="{{globalVariable}}">{{option}}</div>
</ng-container>`
```

For more details, see [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tdalnk)

Answer (score 0):

You have defined `@Input() globalVariable: string;` . So I believe you are passing that `globalVariable` as input from parent component like this :

```
<parent-comp [globalVariable]="globalVariable"></parent-comp>
```

In above line there should be `globalVariable` defined in your parent component ts file.

Rest of your code looks fine to me :

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let option of options">
   <label class="{{globalVariable}}">{{option}}</label>
</ng-container>
```